# Django API : Create Serializer Issue

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm working on my Django web application and I'm beginning API part.
I have a Create Serializer class like this :

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    class Meta :
        model = Individu
        fields = [
            'Etat',
            'Civilite',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'Sexe',
            'Statut',
            'DateNaissance',
            'VilleNaissance',
            'PaysNaissance',
            'Nationalite1',
            'Nationalite2',
            'Profession',
            'Adresse',
            'Ville',
            'Zip',
            'Pays',
            'Mail',
            'Telephone',
            'Image',
            'CarteIdentite',
            ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        obj = Individu.objects.create(**validated_data)
        IdentityIndividuResumeView.get_context_data(obj.id)
        return obj
```

In this class, I have my `create function` which should redirect to `IdentityIndividuResumeView class` when my person is created.

```
class IdentityIndividuResumeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView) :

    template_name = 'Identity_Individu_Resume.html'
    model = Individu

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs) :

        context_data = super(IdentityIndividuResumeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        id = self.kwargs['id']
        personne = get_object_or_404(Individu, pk=id)

        NIU = lib.Individu_Recherche.NIUGeneratorIndividu(personne)
        personne.NumeroIdentification = NIU
        ...
```

But I don't overcome to pass argument in my function `get_context_data`. I'm getting this issue :

```
File "/Users/valentin/Desktop/Identity/api/serializers.py" in create
  80.       IdentityIndividuResumeView.get_context_data(obj.id)

File "/Users/valentin/Desktop/Identity/views.py" in get_context_data
  228.         context_data = super(IdentityIndividuResumeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /Api/Identification/create/
Exception Value: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

**EDIT :**

It works with `FBV model`, but I would like to convert this to `CBV` :

```
@login_required 
def Identity_Individu_Resume(request, id) :

     personne = get_object_or_404(Individu, pk=id)

     NIU = lib.Individu_Recherche.NIUGeneratorIndividu(personne)
     personne.NumeroIdentification = NIU
     ...
```

and serializers.py file :

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    obj = Individu.objects.create(**validated_data)
    Identity_Individu_Resume(self.context.get('request'), obj.id)
    return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for your self object at /Users/valentin/Desktop/Identity/views.py line 228 self object is wrong.

I mean Content in the self object is of not proper type.

Answer (score 0):

The `create` function of the serializer is calling using the class object `IdentityIndividuResumeView.get_context_data(obj.id)` and not the instance of the class. While in the function based view, you are passing all the required arguments. That's why it is working for it.

Comment: Yes, but I tried `IdentityIndividuResumeView.get_context_data(obj.id)` and it doesn't work with CBV model.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, `IdentityIndividuResumeView` is a class object. In `super(IdentityIndividuResumeView, self)`, `self` is expected to be an instance of the class which is not the case right now. So throwing an error

Comment: So I should add something like this ? `IdentityIndividuResumeView.get_context_data(self, obj.id)` and `obj.id` corresponding to `**kwargs` right ?

Comment: No. It won't work because self will be instance of your serializer object. In my opinion, you should not call method of view class in the serializer. If you need to pass any extra data to serializer, use context parameter. Are you using the values of `get_context_data` method anywhere in your `create` method?

Comment: `context` parameter can be used while creating the instance of serializer.